# Getting UV tangent.w in Shader Editor

Tags: scripting, node-editor, normals, mathematics

[image: Image of tangent node that I use]

I recently discovered the tangent node and learned a lot by messing around with it, but something I noticed is that the tangent vector is 4-dimensional in programs such as Unity, with the 4th, tangent.w, being the bitangent sign (at least according to my research).

I’d like to know if this can be applied to Blender as well.

The closest lead I have is that the bitangent itself can be found for vertices via scripting with [meshloop](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshLoop.html). However, with UVs I have no idea, and even less when it comes to translating that into a node I can use. (If I can even use it in the first place.)

With that said, any help is appreciated! I’m relatively new to the more technical aspects of shading, so I apologize if I got any terminology wrong.